# How to write a Flow Type definition for ImmutableJS Types?

Tags: javascript, immutable.js, flowtype

I see that [ImmutableJS has flow type annotations now](https://github.com/facebook/immutable-js/issues/203z) but how do I define the type? For example:

```
const state : ??? = Immutable.fromJS({ name: 'chet', tags: ['something']})
```

I can define the type from normal JS but how do I say that this is an Immutable.Map with certain keys?

Answer (score 3):

The problem right now is that immutable flow types only support one type definition for each key and value combination.

So immutable.Maps accepts `Map<keyType, valueType>`

and immutable.List accepts `List<valueType>`

Immutable.fromJS({ name: 'chet', tags: ['something']})

is equivalent to Map({name: 'chet', tags: List(['something])}

so, your type definition would be

`Map<(string) | ('name', 'tags'), string | List<string>>`

Comment: Do Immutable flow types still only support one type definition for each key and value combination? I'd like to do something like `Map<{name: string, tags: List<string>}>` but can't figure out how

Comment: The standard approach for that sort of specificity is to use an immutable record. It's not perfect by any means, but it does the trick

Comment: @I2silver Ah, I see. If I'm using Redux then for state management, would it be a good idea to make the entire state tree an Immutable JS Record?

Comment: It's definitely convenient only having to deal with immutable objects in the state tree. I'm not religious about it, but it can make things easier

Answer (score 3):

Use [Record](https://facebook.github.io/immutable-js/docs/#/Record) instead of Map (or fromJS). It's not the prettiest addition to your code, especially if your state has nested `Record`s, but the type checking support is great.

```
// @flow

import { Record, List } from 'immutable';
import type { RecordFactory, RecordOf } from 'immutable';

type StateProps = {
  name: string,
  tags: List<string>,
}

type State = RecordOf<StateProps>;

const makeState: RecordFactory<StateProps> = Record({
  name: '',
  tags: List(),
});

const state: State = makeState({
  name: 'chet',
  tags: List(['something']),
});

// Or, to to create an instance of the default
// const _state: State = makeState();
```

Answer (score 1):

I would write this type as

```
const state: Map<string, any>
```

This says that state is going to be of type Map, and the map will have string keys and (name, tags), and the values will be any.
Also, note, you'll have to do

```
import type { Map } from 'immutable';
```

or else it will think it's the native type Map and you'll see errors like Map does not have a get or getIn method.